# Character 'E' in OData v4's function string parameter is causing 404 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, action, odata

I'm having a weird problem when I'm writing an OData function. This function takes a string parameter, and returns a collection of DTOs. This function works fine as long as the string parameter doesn't contain the character 'E'. I'm wondering if it is a bug in the UrlRoutingModule or something?

The method declaration is:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("GetMaintainingLogByIdNumber(IdNumber={IdNumber})")]
public IEnumerable<MaintainingLogDto> GetMaintainingLogByIdNumber([FromODataUri]string IdNumber)
```

And the code to register this function in Edm Model is:

```
modelBuilder
.Function("GetMaintainingLogByIdNumber")
.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<MaintainingLogDto>("MaintainingLog")
.Parameter<string>("IdNumber");
```

If I call this function with

```
http://hostname/odata/GetMaintainingLogByIdNumber(IdNumber='0001100110124221929')
```

The function returns correct result. And this url, which includes an ’E' will cause a 404

```
http://hostname/odata/GetMaintainingLogByIdNumber(IdNumber='000110011E0124221929')
```

All other characters are working fine.

Comment: +1, I admit that I found your error very unlikely so I had to check it myself. I can confirm it, I managed to reproduce it too. I believe it is because WebAPI thinks the parameter is a number and not a string, if the first char isn't a number it does work. Also, if the parameter value is `123.0` I get the 404 error too. I'll report the bug to Microsoft in the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a bug of the URL parser of our ODataLib implementation, a Github issue has been opened in our issue tracker: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/3 and it is fixed in our internal code base. You should be able to see the fix in our next Nuget release and the corresponding fix code in our next Github source update.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. I can confirm the issue is fixed in latest Nuget package. Run this command in your package manager window: `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -Version 5.4.0`